# how to distinguish or discriminate?

Tags: verbs

**We distinguish in order to separate or keep things apart which might otherwise be   confounded.We discriminate with the further view of showing where in their differences  consist.**
 **Hence discrimination must always be nice, particular, and exact, dissecting, as it were the  things discriminated. distinction maybe exact or not, minute or tough, broad or nice.**

I cannot really get what these explanations mean. Would anyone possibly show me their meaning, especially by some example?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'll try doing what you didn't ask: discriminate the two words the way I understand them, in simple words. Being able to "distinguish" is being able to "tell" that those things are different. To "discriminate" is to show such a difference or differences, intentionally, purposefully, explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the author refers to the word *distinguish* as having a meaning close to one of the following ([from The Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/distinguish)):

> transitive verb
>
> 2 a :  to mark as separate or different
>
> b :  to separate into kinds, classes, or categories

Whereas, he seems to be describing [*discriminate*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/discriminate) as

> to notice and understand that one thing is different from another thing : **to recognize a difference between things**

So, in *discriminate*, the emphasis is put onto recognizing the very aspects that differentiate one group from another.

Whereas in *distinguish* , we don't elaborate on why they are different. We just state the fact that they are.

An example that denotes this particular meaning for *discriminate* would be:

> ['The attacks in Jordan, just like those before it in Indonesia, Egypt, Spain and the United States, demonstrate that terrorism does not **discriminate by race, ethnicity or region**. Instead, terrorists **indiscriminately target** those seeking to live a peaceful, loving and free life.' -    Allyson Schwartz](http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/a/allysonsch332410.html#V2R3HE50DPxgzbqb.99)

And for *distinguish*, it would be:

> ['Education... has produced a vast population able to read but unable to **distinguish** what is worth reading.' - G. M. Trevelyan](http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/g/gmtrevel104887.html#0AD2SEOQSEoT5teS.99)